# Unexpected behavior of make -I

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to compile a program from a cmake generated makefile. I want to use the headers found in `/usr/include` (Specifically utmpx.h), as I'm getting this compile error:

```
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/qtermwidget5.dir/lib/kpty.cpp.o
/Users/a7c/qtermwidget/qtermwidget-master/lib/kpty.cpp:506:26: error: no member named 'ut_name' in 'utmpx'
        strncpy(l_struct.ut_name, user, sizeof(l_struct.ut_name));
```

and I belive using `/usr/include/utmpx.h` will fix the problem, because I have verified it has `define ut_user ut_name` in it. However, `make -I/usr` results in the same error, as does `make -I/usr/include`.

Is there any easy way to validate that the specified headers are being used? Or, could it be some other problem?

**EDIT**

Here's the relevant section of the header:

```
#ifdef _UTMPX_COMPAT
#define ut_user ut_name
#define ut_xtime ut_tv.tv_sec
#endif /* _UTMPX_COMPAT */

struct utmpx {
        char ut_user[_UTX_USERSIZE];    /* login name */
        char ut_id[_UTX_IDSIZE];        /* id */
        char ut_line[_UTX_LINESIZE];    /* tty name */
        pid_t ut_pid;                   /* process id creating the entry */
        short ut_type;                  /* type of this entry */
        struct timeval ut_tv;           /* time entry was created */
        char ut_host[_UTX_HOSTSIZE];    /* host name */
        __uint32_t ut_pad[16];          /* reserved for future use */
};
```

**EDIT 2**
Full utmpx.h:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2004-2006 Apple Computer, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * @APPLE_LICENSE_HEADER_START@
 * 
 * This file contains Original Code and/or Modifications of Original Code
 * as defined in and that are subject to the Apple Public Source License
 * Version 2.0 (the 'License'). You may not use this file except in
 * compliance with the License. Please obtain a copy of the License at
 * http://www.opensource.apple.com/apsl/ and read it before using this
 * file.
 * 
 * The Original Code and all software distributed under the License are
 * distributed on an 'AS IS' basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EITHER
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, AND APPLE HEREBY DISCLAIMS ALL SUCH WARRANTIES,
 * INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION, ANY WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, QUIET ENJOYMENT OR NON-INFRINGEMENT.
 * Please see the License for the specific language governing rights and
 * limitations under the License.
 * 
 * @APPLE_LICENSE_HEADER_END@
 */
/*  $NetBSD: utmpx.h,v 1.11 2003/08/26 16:48:32 wiz Exp $    */

/*-
 * Copyright (c) 2002 The NetBSD Foundation, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This code is derived from software contributed to The NetBSD Foundation
 * by Christos Zoulas.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 3. All advertising materials mentioning features or use of this software
 *    must display the following acknowledgement:
 *        This product includes software developed by the NetBSD
 *        Foundation, Inc. and its contributors.
 * 4. Neither the name of The NetBSD Foundation nor the names of its
 *    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE NETBSD FOUNDATION, INC. AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
 * TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE FOUNDATION OR CONTRIBUTORS
 * BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
 * CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
#ifndef _UTMPX_H_
#define _UTMPX_H_

#include <_types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/cdefs.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#include <sys/_types/_pid_t.h>

#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
#include <sys/_types/_uid_t.h>
#endif /* !_POSIX_C_SOURCE || _DARWIN_C_SOURCE */

#define _PATH_UTMPX     "/var/run/utmpx"

#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
#define UTMPX_FILE  _PATH_UTMPX
#endif /* !_POSIX_C_SOURCE || _DARWIN_C_SOURCE */

#define _UTX_USERSIZE   256 /* matches MAXLOGNAME */
#define _UTX_LINESIZE   32
#define _UTX_IDSIZE 4
#define _UTX_HOSTSIZE   256

#define EMPTY       0
#define RUN_LVL     1
#define BOOT_TIME   2
#define OLD_TIME    3
#define NEW_TIME    4
#define INIT_PROCESS    5
#define LOGIN_PROCESS   6
#define USER_PROCESS    7
#define DEAD_PROCESS    8

#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
#define ACCOUNTING  9
#define SIGNATURE   10
#define SHUTDOWN_TIME   11

#define UTMPX_AUTOFILL_MASK         0x8000
#define UTMPX_DEAD_IF_CORRESPONDING_MASK    0x4000

/* notify(3) change notification name */
#define UTMPX_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION       "com.apple.system.utmpx"
#endif /* !_POSIX_C_SOURCE || _DARWIN_C_SOURCE */

/*
 * The following structure describes the fields of the utmpx entries
 * stored in _PATH_UTMPX. This is not the format the
 * entries are stored in the files, and application should only access
 * entries using routines described in getutxent(3).
 */

#ifdef _UTMPX_COMPAT
#define ut_user ut_name
#define ut_xtime ut_tv.tv_sec
#endif /* _UTMPX_COMPAT */

struct utmpx {
    char ut_user[_UTX_USERSIZE];    /* login name */
    char ut_id[_UTX_IDSIZE];    /* id */
    char ut_line[_UTX_LINESIZE];    /* tty name */
    pid_t ut_pid;           /* process id creating the entry */
    short ut_type;          /* type of this entry */
    struct timeval ut_tv;       /* time entry was created */
    char ut_host[_UTX_HOSTSIZE];    /* host name */
    __uint32_t ut_pad[16];      /* reserved for future use */
};

#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
struct lastlogx {
    struct timeval ll_tv;       /* time entry was created */
    char ll_line[_UTX_LINESIZE];    /* tty name */
    char ll_host[_UTX_HOSTSIZE];    /* host name */
};
#endif /* !_POSIX_C_SOURCE || _DARWIN_C_SOURCE */

__BEGIN_DECLS

void    endutxent(void);

#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
void    endutxent_wtmp(void) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
struct lastlogx *
    getlastlogx(uid_t, struct lastlogx *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
struct lastlogx *
    getlastlogxbyname(const char*, struct lastlogx *)__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
struct utmp;    /* forward reference */
void    getutmp(const struct utmpx *, struct utmp *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_9, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_7_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
void    getutmpx(const struct utmp *, struct utmpx *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_9, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_7_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
#endif /* !_POSIX_C_SOURCE || _DARWIN_C_SOURCE */

struct utmpx *
    getutxent(void);

#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
struct utmpx *
    getutxent_wtmp(void) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
#endif /* !_POSIX_C_SOURCE || _DARWIN_C_SOURCE */

struct utmpx *
    getutxid(const struct utmpx *);
struct utmpx *
    getutxline(const struct utmpx *);
struct utmpx *
    pututxline(const struct utmpx *);
void    setutxent(void);

#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
void    setutxent_wtmp(int) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
int utmpxname(const char *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
int wtmpxname(const char *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
#endif /* !_POSIX_C_SOURCE || _DARWIN_C_SOURCE */

__END_DECLS

#endif /* !_UTMPX_H_ */
```

Full ktpy.cpp:

```
    /*

   This file is part of the KDE libraries
   Copyright (C) 2002 Waldo Bastian <bastian@kde.org>
   Copyright (C) 2002-2003,2007 Oswald Buddenhagen <ossi@kde.org>

    Rewritten for QT4 by e_k <e_k at users.sourceforge.net>, Copyright (C)2008

   This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Library General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Library General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU Library General Public License
   along with this library; see the file COPYING.LIB.  If not, write to
   the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor,
   Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
*/

#include "kpty_p.h"

#include <QtDebug>


#if defined(__FreeBSD__) || defined(__NetBSD__) || defined(__OpenBSD__) || defined(__DragonFly__)
#define HAVE_LOGIN
#define HAVE_LIBUTIL_H
#endif

#ifdef __sgi
#define __svr4__
#endif

#ifdef __osf__
#define _OSF_SOURCE
#include <float.h>
#endif

#ifdef _AIX
#define _ALL_SOURCE
#endif

// __USE_XOPEN isn't defined by default in ICC
// (needed for ptsname(), grantpt() and unlockpt())
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
#  ifndef __USE_XOPEN
#    define __USE_XOPEN
#  endif
#endif

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/param.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <grp.h>

#if defined(HAVE_PTY_H)
# include <pty.h>
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_LIBUTIL_H
# include <libutil.h>
#elif defined(HAVE_UTIL_H)
# include <util.h>
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_UTEMPTER
extern "C" {
# include <utempter.h>
}
#else
# include <utmp.h>
# ifdef HAVE_UTMPX
#  include <utmpx.h>
# endif
# if !defined(_PATH_UTMPX) && defined(_UTMPX_FILE)
#  define _PATH_UTMPX _UTMPX_FILE
# endif
# ifdef HAVE_UPDWTMPX
#  if !defined(_PATH_WTMPX) && defined(_WTMPX_FILE)
#   define _PATH_WTMPX _WTMPX_FILE
#  endif
# endif
#endif

/* for HP-UX (some versions) the extern C is needed, and for other
   platforms it doesn't hurt */
extern "C" {
#include <termios.h>
#if defined(HAVE_TERMIO_H)
# include <termio.h> // struct winsize on some systems
#endif
}

#if defined (_HPUX_SOURCE)
# define _TERMIOS_INCLUDED
# include <bsdtty.h>
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_SYS_STROPTS_H
# include <sys/stropts.h> // Defines I_PUSH
# define _NEW_TTY_CTRL
#endif

#if defined (__FreeBSD__) || defined(__FreeBSD_kernel__) || defined (__NetBSD__) || defined (__OpenBSD__) || defined (__bsdi__) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined (__DragonFly__)
# define _tcgetattr(fd, ttmode) ioctl(fd, TIOCGETA, (char *)ttmode)
#else
# if defined(_HPUX_SOURCE) || defined(__Lynx__) || defined (__CYGWIN__) || defined(__GNU__)
#  define _tcgetattr(fd, ttmode) tcgetattr(fd, ttmode)
# else
#  define _tcgetattr(fd, ttmode) ioctl(fd, TCGETS, (char *)ttmode)
# endif
#endif

#if defined (__FreeBSD__) || defined(__FreeBSD_kernel__) || defined (__NetBSD__) || defined (__OpenBSD__) || defined (__bsdi__) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined (__DragonFly__)
# define _tcsetattr(fd, ttmode) ioctl(fd, TIOCSETA, (char *)ttmode)
#else
# if defined(_HPUX_SOURCE) || defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(__GNU__)
#  define _tcsetattr(fd, ttmode) tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, ttmode)
# else
#  define _tcsetattr(fd, ttmode) ioctl(fd, TCSETS, (char *)ttmode)
# endif
#endif

//#include <kdebug.h>
//#include <kstandarddirs.h>  // findExe

// not defined on HP-UX for example
#ifndef CTRL
# define CTRL(x) ((x) & 037)
#endif

#define TTY_GROUP "tty"

///////////////////////
// private functions //
///////////////////////

//////////////////
// private data //
//////////////////

KPtyPrivate::KPtyPrivate(KPty* parent) :
        masterFd(-1), slaveFd(-1), ownMaster(true), q_ptr(parent)
{
}

KPtyPrivate::~KPtyPrivate()
{
}

bool KPtyPrivate::chownpty(bool)
{
//    return !QProcess::execute(KStandardDirs::findExe("kgrantpty"),
//        QStringList() << (grant?"--grant":"--revoke") << QString::number(masterFd));
    return true;
}

/////////////////////////////
// public member functions //
/////////////////////////////

KPty::KPty() :
        d_ptr(new KPtyPrivate(this))
{
}

KPty::KPty(KPtyPrivate *d) :
        d_ptr(d)
{
    d_ptr->q_ptr = this;
}

KPty::~KPty()
{
    close();
    delete d_ptr;
}

bool KPty::open()
{
    Q_D(KPty);

    if (d->masterFd >= 0)
        return true;

    d->ownMaster = true;

    QByteArray ptyName;

    // Find a master pty that we can open ////////////////////////////////

    // Because not all the pty animals are created equal, they want to
    // be opened by several different methods.

    // We try, as we know them, one by one.

#ifdef HAVE_OPENPTY

    char ptsn[PATH_MAX];
    if (::openpty( &d->masterFd, &d->slaveFd, ptsn, 0, 0)) {
        d->masterFd = -1;
        d->slaveFd = -1;
        qWarning(175) << "Can't open a pseudo teletype";
        return false;
    }
    d->ttyName = ptsn;

#else

#ifdef HAVE__GETPTY // irix

    char *ptsn = _getpty(&d->masterFd, O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR, 0);
    if (ptsn) {
        d->ttyName = ptsn;
        goto grantedpt;
    }

#elif defined(HAVE_PTSNAME) || defined(TIOCGPTN)

#ifdef HAVE_POSIX_OPENPT
    d->masterFd = ::posix_openpt(O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY);
#elif defined(HAVE_GETPT)
    d->masterFd = ::getpt();
#elif defined(PTM_DEVICE)
    d->masterFd = ::open(PTM_DEVICE, O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY);
#else
# error No method to open a PTY master detected.
#endif
    if (d->masterFd >= 0) {
#ifdef HAVE_PTSNAME
        char *ptsn = ptsname(d->masterFd);
        if (ptsn) {
            d->ttyName = ptsn;
#else
    int ptyno;
    if (!ioctl(d->masterFd, TIOCGPTN, &ptyno)) {
        d->ttyName = QByteArray("/dev/pts/") + QByteArray::number(ptyno);
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_GRANTPT
            if (!grantpt(d->masterFd)) {
                goto grantedpt;
            }
#else

    goto gotpty;
#endif
        }
        ::close(d->masterFd);
        d->masterFd = -1;
    }
#endif // HAVE_PTSNAME || TIOCGPTN

    // Linux device names, FIXME: Trouble on other systems?
    for (const char * s3 = "pqrstuvwxyzabcde"; *s3; s3++) {
        for (const char * s4 = "0123456789abcdef"; *s4; s4++) {
            ptyName = QString().sprintf("/dev/pty%c%c", *s3, *s4).toUtf8();
            d->ttyName = QString().sprintf("/dev/tty%c%c", *s3, *s4).toUtf8();

            d->masterFd = ::open(ptyName.data(), O_RDWR);
            if (d->masterFd >= 0) {
#ifdef Q_OS_SOLARIS
                /* Need to check the process group of the pty.
                 * If it exists, then the slave pty is in use,
                 * and we need to get another one.
                 */
                int pgrp_rtn;
                if (ioctl(d->masterFd, TIOCGPGRP, &pgrp_rtn) == 0 || errno != EIO) {
                    ::close(d->masterFd);
                    d->masterFd = -1;
                    continue;
                }
#endif /* Q_OS_SOLARIS */
                if (!access(d->ttyName.data(),R_OK|W_OK)) { // checks availability based on permission bits
                    if (!geteuid()) {
                        struct group * p = getgrnam(TTY_GROUP);
                        if (!p) {
                            p = getgrnam("wheel");
                        }
                        gid_t gid = p ? p->gr_gid : getgid ();

                        if (!chown(d->ttyName.data(), getuid(), gid)) {
                            chmod(d->ttyName.data(), S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IWGRP);
                        }
                    }
                    goto gotpty;
                }
                ::close(d->masterFd);
                d->masterFd = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    qWarning() << "Can't open a pseudo teletype";
    return false;

gotpty:
    struct stat st;
    if (stat(d->ttyName.data(), &st)) {
        return false; // this just cannot happen ... *cough*  Yeah right, I just
        // had it happen when pty #349 was allocated.  I guess
        // there was some sort of leak?  I only had a few open.
    }
    if (((st.st_uid != getuid()) ||
            (st.st_mode & (S_IRGRP|S_IXGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH|S_IXOTH))) &&
            !d->chownpty(true)) {
        qWarning()
        << "chownpty failed for device " << ptyName << "::" << d->ttyName
        << "\nThis means the communication can be eavesdropped." << endl;
    }

#if defined (HAVE__GETPTY) || defined (HAVE_GRANTPT)
grantedpt:
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_REVOKE
    revoke(d->ttyName.data());
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_UNLOCKPT
    unlockpt(d->masterFd);
#elif defined(TIOCSPTLCK)
    int flag = 0;
    ioctl(d->masterFd, TIOCSPTLCK, &flag);
#endif

    d->slaveFd = ::open(d->ttyName.data(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (d->slaveFd < 0) {
        qWarning() << "Can't open slave pseudo teletype";
        ::close(d->masterFd);
        d->masterFd = -1;
        return false;
    }

#if (defined(__svr4__) || defined(__sgi__))
    // Solaris
    ioctl(d->slaveFd, I_PUSH, "ptem");
    ioctl(d->slaveFd, I_PUSH, "ldterm");
#endif

#endif /* HAVE_OPENPTY */

    fcntl(d->masterFd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
    fcntl(d->slaveFd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);

    return true;
}

bool KPty::open(int fd)
{
#if !defined(HAVE_PTSNAME) && !defined(TIOCGPTN)
     qWarning() << "Unsupported attempt to open pty with fd" << fd;
     return false;
#else
    Q_D(KPty);

    if (d->masterFd >= 0) {
        qWarning() << "Attempting to open an already open pty";
         return false;
    }

    d->ownMaster = false;

# ifdef HAVE_PTSNAME
    char *ptsn = ptsname(fd);
    if (ptsn) {
        d->ttyName = ptsn;
# else
    int ptyno;
    if (!ioctl(fd, TIOCGPTN, &ptyno)) {
        char buf[32];
        sprintf(buf, "/dev/pts/%d", ptyno);
        d->ttyName = buf;
# endif
    } else {
        qWarning() << "Failed to determine pty slave device for fd" << fd;
        return false;
    }

    d->masterFd = fd;
    if (!openSlave()) {

        d->masterFd = -1;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
#endif
}

void KPty::closeSlave()
{
    Q_D(KPty);

    if (d->slaveFd < 0) {
        return;
    }
    ::close(d->slaveFd);
    d->slaveFd = -1;
}

bool KPty::openSlave()
{
    Q_D(KPty);

    if (d->slaveFd >= 0)
    return true;
    if (d->masterFd < 0) {
    qDebug() << "Attempting to open pty slave while master is closed";
    return false;
    }
    //d->slaveFd = KDE_open(d->ttyName.data(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    d->slaveFd = ::open(d->ttyName.data(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (d->slaveFd < 0) {
    qDebug() << "Can't open slave pseudo teletype";
    return false;
    }
    fcntl(d->slaveFd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
    return true;
}

void KPty::close()
{
    Q_D(KPty);

    if (d->masterFd < 0) {
        return;
    }
    closeSlave();
    // don't bother resetting unix98 pty, it will go away after closing master anyway.
    if (memcmp(d->ttyName.data(), "/dev/pts/", 9)) {
        if (!geteuid()) {
            struct stat st;
            if (!stat(d->ttyName.data(), &st)) {
                chown(d->ttyName.data(), 0, st.st_gid == getgid() ? 0 : -1);
                chmod(d->ttyName.data(), S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH);
            }
        } else {
            fcntl(d->masterFd, F_SETFD, 0);
            d->chownpty(false);
        }
    }
    ::close(d->masterFd);
    d->masterFd = -1;
}

void KPty::setCTty()
{
    Q_D(KPty);

    // Setup job control //////////////////////////////////

    // Become session leader, process group leader,
    // and get rid of the old controlling terminal.
    setsid();

    // make our slave pty the new controlling terminal.
#ifdef TIOCSCTTY
    ioctl(d->slaveFd, TIOCSCTTY, 0);
#else
    // __svr4__ hack: the first tty opened after setsid() becomes controlling tty
    ::close(::open(d->ttyName, O_WRONLY, 0));
#endif

    // make our new process group the foreground group on the pty
    int pgrp = getpid();
#if defined(_POSIX_VERSION) || defined(__svr4__)
    tcsetpgrp(d->slaveFd, pgrp);
#elif defined(TIOCSPGRP)
    ioctl(d->slaveFd, TIOCSPGRP, (char *)&pgrp);
#endif
}

void KPty::login(const char * user, const char * remotehost)
{
#ifdef HAVE_UTEMPTER
    Q_D(KPty);

    addToUtmp(d->ttyName, remotehost, d->masterFd);
    Q_UNUSED(user);
#else
# ifdef HAVE_UTMPX
    struct utmpx l_struct;
# else
    struct utmp l_struct;
# endif
    memset(&l_struct, 0, sizeof(l_struct));
    // note: strncpy without terminators _is_ correct here. man 4 utmp

    if (user) {
        strncpy(l_struct.ut_name, user, sizeof(l_struct.ut_name));
    }

    if (remotehost) {
        strncpy(l_struct.ut_host, remotehost, sizeof(l_struct.ut_host));
# ifdef HAVE_STRUCT_UTMP_UT_SYSLEN
        l_struct.ut_syslen = qMin(strlen(remotehost), sizeof(l_struct.ut_host));
# endif
    }

# ifndef __GLIBC__
    Q_D(KPty);
    const char * str_ptr = d->ttyName.data();
    if (!memcmp(str_ptr, "/dev/", 5)) {
        str_ptr += 5;
    }
    strncpy(l_struct.ut_line, str_ptr, sizeof(l_struct.ut_line));
#  ifdef HAVE_STRUCT_UTMP_UT_ID
    strncpy(l_struct.ut_id,
            str_ptr + strlen(str_ptr) - sizeof(l_struct.ut_id),
            sizeof(l_struct.ut_id));
#  endif
# endif

# ifdef HAVE_UTMPX
    gettimeofday(&l_struct.ut_tv, 0);
# else
    l_struct.ut_time = time(0);
# endif

# ifdef HAVE_LOGIN
#  ifdef HAVE_LOGINX
    ::loginx(&l_struct);
#  else
    ::login(&l_struct);
#  endif
# else
#  ifdef HAVE_STRUCT_UTMP_UT_TYPE
    l_struct.ut_type = USER_PROCESS;
#  endif
#  ifdef HAVE_STRUCT_UTMP_UT_PID
    l_struct.ut_pid = getpid();
#   ifdef HAVE_STRUCT_UTMP_UT_SESSION
    l_struct.ut_session = getsid(0);
#   endif
#  endif
#  ifdef HAVE_UTMPX
    utmpxname(_PATH_UTMPX);
    setutxent();
    pututxline(&l_struct);
    endutxent();
#   ifdef HAVE_UPDWTMPX
    updwtmpx(_PATH_WTMPX, &l_struct);
#   endif
#  else
    utmpname(_PATH_UTMP);
    setutent();
    pututline(&l_struct);
    endutent();
    updwtmp(_PATH_WTMP, &l_struct);
#  endif
# endif
#endif
}

void KPty::logout()
{
#ifdef HAVE_UTEMPTER
    Q_D(KPty);

    removeLineFromUtmp(d->ttyName, d->masterFd);
#else
    Q_D(KPty);

    const char *str_ptr = d->ttyName.data();
    if (!memcmp(str_ptr, "/dev/", 5)) {
        str_ptr += 5;
    }
# ifdef __GLIBC__
    else {
        const char * sl_ptr = strrchr(str_ptr, '/');
        if (sl_ptr) {
            str_ptr = sl_ptr + 1;
        }
    }
# endif
# ifdef HAVE_LOGIN
#  ifdef HAVE_LOGINX
    ::logoutx(str_ptr, 0, DEAD_PROCESS);
#  else
    ::logout(str_ptr);
#  endif
# else
#  ifdef HAVE_UTMPX
    struct utmpx l_struct, *ut;
#  else
    struct utmp l_struct, *ut;
#  endif
    memset(&l_struct, 0, sizeof(l_struct));

    strncpy(l_struct.ut_line, str_ptr, sizeof(l_struct.ut_line));

#  ifdef HAVE_UTMPX
    utmpxname(_PATH_UTMPX);
    setutxent();
    if ((ut = getutxline(&l_struct))) {
#  else
    utmpname(_PATH_UTMP);
    setutent();
    if ((ut = getutline(&l_struct))) {
#  endif
        memset(ut->ut_name, 0, sizeof(*ut->ut_name));
        memset(ut->ut_host, 0, sizeof(*ut->ut_host));
#  ifdef HAVE_STRUCT_UTMP_UT_SYSLEN
        ut->ut_syslen = 0;
#  endif
#  ifdef HAVE_STRUCT_UTMP_UT_TYPE
        ut->ut_type = DEAD_PROCESS;
#  endif
#  ifdef HAVE_UTMPX
        gettimeofday(&ut->ut_tv, 0);
        pututxline(ut);
    }
    endutxent();
#  else
    ut->ut_time = time(0);
    pututline(ut);
}
endutent();
#  endif
# endif
#endif
}

// XXX Supposedly, tc[gs]etattr do not work with the master on Solaris.
// Please verify.

bool KPty::tcGetAttr(struct ::termios * ttmode) const
{
    Q_D(const KPty);

    return _tcgetattr(d->masterFd, ttmode) == 0;
}

bool KPty::tcSetAttr(struct ::termios * ttmode)
{
    Q_D(KPty);

    return _tcsetattr(d->masterFd, ttmode) == 0;
}

bool KPty::setWinSize(int lines, int columns)
{
    Q_D(KPty);

    struct winsize winSize;
    memset(&winSize, 0, sizeof(winSize));
    winSize.ws_row = (unsigned short)lines;
    winSize.ws_col = (unsigned short)columns;
    return ioctl(d->masterFd, TIOCSWINSZ, (char *)&winSize) == 0;
}

bool KPty::setEcho(bool echo)
{
    struct ::termios ttmode;
    if (!tcGetAttr(&ttmode)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!echo) {
        ttmode.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    } else {
        ttmode.c_lflag |= ECHO;
    }
    return tcSetAttr(&ttmode);
}

const char * KPty::ttyName() const
{
    Q_D(const KPty);

    return d->ttyName.data();
}

int KPty::masterFd() const
{
    Q_D(const KPty);

    return d->masterFd;
}

int KPty::slaveFd() const
{
    Q_D(const KPty);

    return d->slaveFd;
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `utmpx`?

Comment: @Kevin I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. It's a header file. Maybe this will answer your question? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp)

Comment: I meant the struct.

Comment: The compiler says `utmpx` does not contain a member named `ut_name`. I believe the compiler.

Comment: @Kevin edited the question

Comment: It's clearly not replacing ut_name with ut_user since the compiler is complaining about ut_name. Is _UTMPX_COMPAT defined?

Comment: See my edited comment. My guess is _UTMPX_COMPAT is not defined so ut_user isn't replaced with ut_name.

Comment: If you were expecting `#define ut_user ut_name` to have an effect, you shouldn't. You got it backwards.

Comment: @CareyGregory I think that would still work. It would replace ut_user with ut_name in the struct's definition.

Comment: @Kevin Except clearly it didn't. OP isn't showing us all the code, so who knows where the `#define` is placed relative to the `#include` statements.

Comment: `make -I/usr CFLAGS=-D_UTMPX_COMPAT` Resulted in the same error

Comment: @ChildishJack what happens if you instead use ut_user like you're supposed to? If the #define gets hit all occurrences of ut_user will be replaced so it won't be an issue either way

Comment: Show us all the code. You're making an easy mistake to fix but it's impossible to fix if we can't see it.

Comment: @CareyGregory I've updated the post. I didn't write this software - let me know if you'd like me to post anything else.